# error while using perl template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am tried to get this data using template toolkit but I am unable to get.

```
$var1={
      'Object'=>[
                {
                 'Component'=>[
                               {
                                'type'=>'analog',
                                'name'=>'Temp',
                                'value'=>'23'
                                },
                                 {
                                'type'=>'digital',
                                'name'=>'Temp',
                                'value'=>'22'
                                },
                                 {
                                'type'=>'analog',
                                'name'=>'pressure',
                                'value'=>'23'
                                },
                                 {
                                'type'=>'analog',
                                'name'=>'humidity',
                                'value'=>'23'
                                }
                               ]
                             }
                            ],
                           };
```

I tried like this

```
[% FOREACH st IN Object %]
[% FOREACH st IN Object.Component %]
[% Component.type %][% Component.name %][% Component.value %]
[% END %]
[% END %]
```

I am not able to get the values and aslo it doesn't give any error ,please help how to get this values.

Comment: `object` is lowercase in your data but has a capital `O` in your template.

Comment: sorry i edited now. but still there is problem

Comment: You still have two nested loop variables with the same name in your templates, and then you're not actually using the loop variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template to:

```
[% FOREACH obj IN Object %]
[% FOREACH comp IN obj.Component %]
[% comp.type %] [% comp.name %] [% comp.value %]
[% END %]
[% END %]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `st` variables. I don't remember exactly how TT handles scope but I suspect this not a good thing. You are also trying to extract values from a variable called `Component`. You haven't instantiated a variable called component. Remember that TT under normal circumstances doesn't give you an error if you reference a variable that doesn't exist, it simply outputs nothing.

If you want to change that so you get an error you need to set the [STRICT](http://www.tt2.org/docs/manual/Config.html#section_STRICT) configuration option. Alternatively, set one of the debug options:

```
my $template = Template->new(
    {
       STRICT => 1,      # or
       DEBUG => 'undef'
    });
```

Try something like:

```
[% FOREACH obj in Object %]
    [% FOREACH item in obj.Component %]
      [% obj.type %] [% obj.name %] [% obj.value %]
    [% END %]
[% END %]
```